# randomize the time from time.sleep

Tags: python, time, automation

I'm fairly new to python and have been trying to write a script that automates a string of text. The problem is that i don't know how to randomize the `time.sleep` function. I have also tried adding the `time in range` function but still can't get it to randomize it.

The code looks like this at the moment. I have to get rid of the `time.sleep(40)` to randomize it

```
import time
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller


while True:
    keyboard = Controller()

    time.sleep(40)
    for char in "nnnn":
        keyboard.press(char)
        keyboard.release(char)
        time.sleep(0.21)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the random module

```
import random
import time
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller


while True:
    keyboard = Controller()

    sleep_time = random.randrange(0, 100)
    time.sleep(sleep_time)
    for char in "nnnn":
        keyboard.press(char)
        keyboard.release(char)
        time.sleep(0.21)
```